# How to remove a (big) shared folder from my Dropbox while keeping access to it?

Tags: dropbox

I have some big folders on Dropbox that other people shared with me. They are a place for sharing files, and they constantly grow bigger and bigger. I'd like to avoid keeping them in my own Dropbox (I don't care about offline access and auto-sync, and I **do** care about free space in my Dropbox), but still have access to them when I need something.

How do I do it? :)

Comment: Move them out of your Dropbox folder? They're just files on your harddrive.

Comment: It's a shared folder. If I move them out, I'd remove them for everyone. And I'd also like to have access to new files published in the shared folder.

Comment: There's no way to keep a shared folder without it counting against your quota. Perhaps you should make a second account that they can share with, and you can access the files whenever you like through the web interface. Then have your primary account leave the shared folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request that your contacts share their content to you via a link. This can be done by logging into the web app, at dropbox.com, like so:

[image: Share a folder in Dropbox]

This will allow you to access their content via a browser, while keeping your Dropbox storage unused.